# Yii Facebook Button

Tags: php, facebook, yii

I'm trying to implement a simple Facebook like button in a Yii powered website. The goal is to have the regular "XXX likes something on blabla' message on the user's profile when they click the button. I've looked at different available extensions but none of them seems to be maintained or updated anymore and I would like to use something that's not abandoned by its creators. Anyone with experience on the matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use AddThis with [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/addthis) extension. The extension is not updated for a long time, but it is using the AddThis api and the js libraries are up-to-date.